# Data getting appended in array on scrolling of table view

Tags: arrays, uitableview, append

I am appending data in an array from table view but when I am scrolling the table view the values are getting appended to array even when I am scrolling.....so whenever I am scrolling table view data is getting appended how to stop that???I want to append data to array only once.

Comment: Take secondary array for fill only. Does not make sense to add into primary array and not to reload after that and also lead to get app crash to index out of bound error.

Comment: can't get you.....can you show me an example!!